# a lush black hair

Tags: usage

In English class, we were taught that hair is uncountable and that we use the article when we refer to one strand. However, all the American and British natives in my group agree that the sentence below is correct and acceptable:

> She had beautiful blue eyes and **a lush black hair** most girls would
>   kill for.

Is there a rule in place, or a particular usage, that would explain this? Is it perhaps that when the whole head of hair is referred to or its quality/state described, the indefinite article can be used in a specifying function of sorts?

Comment: I think it's parallel to "The Liverpool that the Beatles came out of". When followed by a restrictive relative clause, NPs that don't usually accept a determiner can have one. I can't characterise it any more closely, though.

Comment: I think "she had lush black hair..." would be the correct way to say it, but because it is close in structure to other common phrases (she had a physique to die for) it is OK to some native speakers. There are other instances of the incorrect word being OK because it's commonly spoken, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: @ColinFine You should write an answer along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think they're using **hair** as synonymous with **mane**.

The normal phrase is "she had lush black hair".

But we *can* use the indefinite article to refer to the hair as a *type* of hair or particular unusual instance of a color.

> She had **a bright red hair** seen only on Broadway in productions of
>   *Annie*.

There, the indefinite article means "a variety of".

Comment: My point exactly!

Answer (score 3):

According to [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and) and the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uncountable), uncountable nouns do not use indefinite articles.

If the sentence refers to someone with one black hair on their head, then the use of an indefinite article is justified, as the singular *hair* is countable.

If necessary, you can add a countable noun  and a preposition to the sentence:

> She had beautiful blue eyes and a **head of** black hair most girls would kill for.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP tells you that several native English speakers find this acceptable. Replying that some authorities say it is not grammatical tells you only that those authorities are wrong, or at least incomplete. Language, and grammaticality, inheres in the people who use and understand it, not in what some book or website says

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63517/discussion-on-answer-by-kman3-a-lush-black-hair). Also, if you can't [Be Nice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), it's better not to comment at all. Disagreement is fine so long as it remains respectful.

Answer (score 1):

"She has a lush black hair" is at very least odd. It is grammatically well formed, in a minimal sense (subject, verb (agreeing with the subject), noun-phrase, the noun phrase composed of singular determiner, two adjectives, singular noun), but the use of countable "hair" makes the meaning very odd.

Therefore *I disagree with the advice that this sentence is correct and acceptable*. It does not sound natural in that context.

The countable/uncountable distinction in English is a developing process. It may, in some future version of English come to function as a type of gender, but in current English, using an uncountable noun in a countable context is merely odd.

In your particular example "a hair" would normally mean "a strand of hair". But the context doesn't allow for that interpretation. Therefore the interpretation must be that the collection of hair on her head is lush. That meaning would normally go with an uncountable noun. A native speaker may on occasion produce a sentence like this (it is grammatically English). However, An editor should remove the word "a". A native speaker may not even notice the word 'a' when reading, as the mind reforms the words in the brain.

So, this sentence is grammatically English, but it is not correct.

Similarly "it was a dirty money" is odd and does not sound natural, for the same reason.